# How to scrape location names from a website using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the pickup branch locations from a car rental website home page. The idea is to see exactly where pickup branches exist for a given company.

I have successfully created this before but this company revamped their website recently and now my code doesn't work. The branch locations seem to be hidden within a form of some sort, the locations only become visible in the html once you click on the pickup location space.

My current code looks as below:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub pickuplocations()
    Dim html As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim headers()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim numrows As Long

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Europcar Branches(2)")
        Set html = New HTMLDocument

            With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", "https://www.europcar.co.za", False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText   'fetches all html from the website

    Dim pickupbranches As Object
    Dim pickupbranchresults()

        Set pickupbranches = html.getElementById("_location-search-widget_15").getElementsByTagName("span") 
        headers = Array("Pickup Location", "Option value") 'for the ws
        numrows = pickupbranches.Length - 1   'sets the row length

        ReDim pickupbranchresults(1 To numrows, 1 To 2)  'sets array size for the results
            For i = 1 To numrows
                pickupbranchresults(i, 1) = pickupbranches.Item(i).innerText 
                pickupbranchresults(i, 2) = pickupbranches.Item(i).Value    
            Next

        With ws

            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers 'sets the column headers
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(pickupbranchresults, 1), UBound(pickupbranchresults, 2)) = pickupbranchresults 
        End With
            End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a question? "my code doesn't work" is not a question.

Comment: It would seem more reasonable to scrape this https://www.europcar.co.za/rental-locations instead. Does this url have all the info you need? If it does then it seems quite easy to get it.

Comment: Your current code won't yield any results because the list of locations is not included in the page's source HTML. It's dynamically loaded when you click on the search bar.

Comment: @StavrosJon So I need to get the code to cycle through each "tab" to scrape the location names. Or alternatively figure out how to click the search bar to get them to dynamically load.

Comment: @Hev if this link https://www.europcar.co.za/rental-locations has all the info you're interested in, then you can get all the locations in JSON format with a single GET request. No need to loop through all tabs separately. If indeed that's what you need, I can post an answer to give you a kick start.

Comment: @StavrosJon Yes that should provide all the locations I need. Forgive my ignorance, but I assume a Json solution will require me to parse into VBA.I am in an office environment and my tools are limited. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: @Hev everything will be done through VBA and it's quite easy, don't worry about it. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code requests the source HTML code and attempts to scrape it.

However, as explained in the comments, the list of locations is dynamically loaded when you click on the search bar and it is not a part of the page's source HTML. For this reason your code will yield no results.

It makes more sense to scrape the page dedicated to the locations:

> https://www.europcar.co.za/rental-locations/

Now, if you navigate to this page and inspect the network traffic in your browser's developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) when the page is loaded, you will see that an `XHR` request is being sent. It looks like so:

[image]

If you go through the Headers and the Params of the request you will see how the url, the body and the headers should look like. In this particular case, there are no parameters and the headers are not essential to the success of the request, so all you need is the url.

The response's payload is in json format. You can inspect its structure using a tool like [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Basically, the JSON consists of the different countries, each country consists of provinces and each province consists of the corresponding branches. Each branch consists of all the corresponding info.

To parse a response like that you need a JSON parser (look at the end of this post).

**TL;DR**

Here's how the code should look like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getLocations()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim url As String, results() As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim responseJSON As Object, country As Object, province As Object, branch As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet")
url = "https://www.europcar.co.za/api/rentalLocations/impressLocations"

With req
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    Set responseJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With

For Each country In responseJSON
    For Each province In country("provinces")
        i = 0
        ReDim results(1 To province("branches").Count, 1 To 5)
        For Each branch In province("branches")
            i = i + 1
            results(i, 1) = country("name")
            results(i, 2) = province("name")
            results(i, 3) = branch("name")
            results(i, 4) = branch("emailAddress")
            results(i, 5) = branch("contactNumber")
        Next branch
        With sht
            Set rng = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
        rng.Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    Next province
Next country

End Sub
```

For demonstration purposes the code above prints out the results in the following way:

[image]

Having in mind the JSON structure and the sample code I provided, you can easily modify it to fit your needs.

For the code to work you will need to add the following references to your project (VBE>Tools>References):

```
 1. Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1
 2. Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

You will also need to add [this JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to your project. Follow the installation instructions in the link and you should be set to go.